# Inapp billing problem with getPurchaseInformation()

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I followed this [tut,](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html) and app is getting null for mService and mContext in getPurchaseInformation().

And how to test inapp billing before publishing. Is it the only way to upload apk file as unpublished draft application and test it,

Looking forward for valuable advices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use test library, see : http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html